# Numpy arrays comparison

Tags: python, pytorch

I have 2 pytorch tensors (single column) of 40 elements To compare them element by element I converted them to numpy arrays with a single column of 40 elements. I want to compare both arrays element by element and if the value is greater than 0.5 in one array make it 1 else 0 and convert the result again to pytorch tensor. How do I do that.

Comment: Could you give us an example of some code you've tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this helps:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
b = np.array([1.1, 2.6, 3.3, 4.6, 5.5])
(np.abs(a-b)>0.5).astype(int)
>>> array([0, 1, 0, 1, 0])
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I just to want to compare two numpy arrays element by element and if the values are same increase the counter and not when not same. In the end tell how many were the correct matches. Thanks in adv..

Comment: If you have two numpy arrays you can also do `np.sum(a == b)` or `(a == b).sum()` where `a` and `b` are your two numpy arrays.

Answer (score 1):

If you only care about the absolute difference, you can use `torch.isclose` with `atol=0.5`:

```
>>> A = torch.arange(10).float()
>>> B = A + torch.randn_like(A) # Add some Gaussian noise to `A`
>>> A
tensor([0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8., 9.])
>>> B
tensor([0.3109, 1.6514, 1.7576, 3.2930, 2.7340, 5.5602, 6.9321, 6.4786, 6.7976,
        9.2342])
>>> torch.isclose(A, B, atol=0.5)
tensor([ True, False,  True,  True, False, False, False, False, False,  True])
```

If you need an asymmetric check, use a normal subtraction check:

```
>>> (B - A) > 0.5
tensor([False,  True, False, False, False,  True,  True, False, False, False])
```

You can use these functions in numpy easily, as well.